# How to add check boxes to a form based on columns in table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Access that allows a user to select a table from a combo box that lists all of the tables using VBA. Based on what table the user selects, I want a set of check boxes to be added to the form. Each check box would represent a column in the chosen table. I have a VBA function that will work with the columns that are chosen through the form after a button is pressed.

How would I make the check boxes appear after the user has chosen a table? I want this form to be applicable to tables that would be added in the future as well so I won't know the number of columns in advance. I can get check boxes to appear dynamically in a Userform but I've heard that they aren't commonly used in Access. I have also heard that there is a limit for the amount of controls that can be added to a form in its lifetime. Is there anyway of renaming controls so that I don't hit this limit?

This is the code that I use to populate the combo box:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
With Me![TableName]
    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If Not (tbl.name Like "MSys*" Or tbl.name Like "~*") Then
            .AddItem tbl.name
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

This is example code that can generate the check boxes in a Userform:

```
Private Sub RetrieveColumns_Click()

Dim TableName As String
Dim MethodName As String
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim fld As Field
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

TableName = Me![TableName]
Set tdf = dbs.CreateTableDef(TableName)

Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(TableName)

With rs
    For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls("Forms.checkbox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
        chkBox.Caption = .Fields(i).name
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be a continuous form / datasheet that shows all table column names with an adjacent checkbox.

Create a table with `ColumnName` (Text) and `Checked` (Yes/No, Default No).

Then when a table is selected:

- delete * from this table,
- In your `.Fields` loop, insert all column names into this table,
- and show the table as subform (or have the table selection combobox in the form header).

With this, you don't need any dynamic controls.

---

Alternatively, for a truly simple solution, use a multi-select listbox.

A listbox has the slightly obscure `RowSourceType` **Field List**.

> The data is a list of field names from a table, query, or SQL statement specified by the RowSource setting.

So all you'd need is to set the `RowSource` property to the selected table name.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of using the extra table.